# Site Category Exclusion based on ContentLabelType: Adwords API

Tags: google-ads-api

How to edit Site Category Exclusion using adwords api.
Presently we can exclude categories manually for each campaign.
The categories are :
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201601/CampaignCriterionService.ContentLabelType
I want to exclude some categories from all the campaigns.

Using googleads example, I came up with this :

```
    from googleads import adwords
    CAMP_ID = '400273340'
    def main(client, camp_id):
      # Initialize appropriate service.
      camp_criterion_service = client.GetService('CampaignCriterionService', version='v201601')

      # Create the ad group criteria.
      ad_group_criteria = [
          # Exclusion criterion.
          {
              'xsi_type': 'CampaignCriterion',
              'campaignId': '400273340',
              'criterion': {
                 'xsi_type': 'ContentLabel',
               'contentLabelType': 'ADULTISH'
              }
          }
      ]

      # Create operations.
      operations = []
      for criterion in ad_group_criteria:
        operations.append({
            'operator': 'REMOVE',
            'operand': criterion
        })

      response = camp_criterion_service.mutate(operations)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
      # Initialize client object.
      adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient.LoadFromStorage()

      main(adwords_client, CAMP_ID)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and couldn't find a solution.

you can see here my solution to the problem (written in PHP):

[Adwords API Exclude Content_label on campaign level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47798493/adwords-api-exclude-content-label-on-campaign-level/47800719#47800719)

but in short, instead of `CampaignCriterion` you need to use `NegativeCampaignCriterion` to exclude this `ContentLabelType`