# Adwords API Exclude Content_label on campaign level

Tags: php, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-ads-api

I've been researching this for a few hours now and still can't figure out a solution.

I intend to exclude some content_labels on the campaign level.
At first, I followed the API examples but those are for 'CustomerNegativeCriteria' that are account level settings (sidenote, I couldn't find these global settings on the AdWords interface).

Then I read more and tried to exclude them using a CampaignCriterion

So I'll create my ContentLabel objects in this way:

```
$criterion = new ContentLabel();
$criterion->setContentLabelType($sLabelType);
$criterion->setType(CriterionType::CONTENT_LABEL);
```

Then, I will add that modifier to a CampaignCriterion object:

```
foreach ($aModifiers as $modifier) {
    $campaignCriterion = new CampaignCriterion($sCampaignId, $isNegative, $modifier, $bidModifier);
    $operation = new CampaignCriterionOperation();
    $operation->setOperand($campaignCriterion);
    $operation->setOperator($operator);
    $operations[] = $operation;
}
```

And then I'll pass those operations to a CampaignCriterionService

```
$oCampaignCriterionService = $this->getCampaignCriterionService();
return $oCampaignCriterionService->mutate($operations);
```

All this is generating this error but I can't find how to solve this. because in the campaign created those values are still in Green (active)

```
Message: [
    CriterionError.CANNOT_TARGET_CRITERION @ operations[0].operand.criterion.contentLabelType; trigger:'DP', 
    CriterionError.CANNOT_TARGET_CRITERION @ operations[1].operand.criterion.contentLabelType; trigger:'ADULTISH', 
    CriterionError.CANNOT_TARGET_CRITERION @ operations[2].operand.criterion.contentLabelType; trigger:'JACKASS', 
    CriterionError.CANNOT_TARGET_CRITERION @ operations[3].operand.criterion.contentLabelType; trigger:'PROFANITY', 
    CriterionError.CANNOT_TARGET_CRITERION @ operations[4].operand.criterion.contentLabelType; trigger:'TRAGEDY', 
    CriterionError.CANNOT_TARGET_CRITERION @ operations[5].operand.criterion.contentLabelType; trigger:'VIDEO_RATING_DV_MA'
]
```

I'm following the tree structure from here but to no avail:
https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/reference/v201710/CampaignCriterionService.ContentLabel?hl=th

Any idea of what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that I was creating `CampaignCriterion` objects and that was the problem, although not explicitly stated anywhere, and not intuitive, there is another type of object called `NegativeCampaignCriterion` and that is the right object to exclude `ContentLabel`'s and `Placement`'s

```
foreach ($aModifiers as $modifier) {
    if ($isNegative) {
        $campaignCriterion = new NegativeCampaignCriterion($sCampaignId, $isNegative, $modifier, $bidModifier);
    } else {
        $campaignCriterion = new CampaignCriterion($sCampaignId, $isNegative, $modifier, $bidModifier);
    }
    $operation = new CampaignCriterionOperation();
    $operation->setOperand($campaignCriterion);
    $operation->setOperator($operator);
    $operations[] = $operation;
}
```